# Name of Font Used on Twitter Android App

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Does anyone know what is the name of the font used on the latest Twitter Android app.

Here are screenshots of the app :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twitter.android&hl=en

Thank you !

Comment: It's [Roboto](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto) isn't it?

Comment: Hi user2505650, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. We have a collection of font identification resources, and it is a good idea to try those first. Please let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increase. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info Please don't be discouraged, we know that using this site can be a learning curve. We *are* happy to have you!

Comment: @AndrewLeach looks that way.

Comment: @Vincent Thank you for your warm welcome, the article you you gave contains very usefull links

Comment: Anytime. Glad to hear that our tag wiki pulls its weight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font looks to be [Roboto](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto) you can find it on google fonts.

[Mirror](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto)